# How to prevent rendering of headers in SimpleMDE markdown editor?

Tags: markdown, wagtail, simplemde

I made a customized version of [wagtail-markdown](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-markdown) so I can define the toolbar of the editor.

The editor used is [SimpleMDE](https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor).

The MarkdownFiled is using a MarkdownTextarea widget.
The widget can attach itself.

```
def render_js_init(self, id_, name, value):
        return 'simplemdeAttach("{0}", {1});'.format(id_, self.toolbar)
```

**simplemdeAttach**

```
/*
 * Used to initialize Simple MDE when Markdown blocks are used in StreamFields.
*/    

function simplemdeAttach(id, toolbar) {
        console.log('For id: '+ id + ' toolbar: ' + toolbar);
        var mde = new SimpleMDE({
            toolbar : toolbar,
            element: document.getElementById(id),
            autofocus: false,
            spellChecker: false,
        });
        mde.render();
        mde.codemirror.on("change", function(){
            $('#' + id).val(mde.value());
        });
    }
```

**Editor in Wagtailadmin**

[image: widget at work]

Manualy inserted hashes shouldn’t be rendered.

I investigated the javascript code of SimpleMDE but I can’t figure out how to prevent the rendering.

Does someone have a clue?

Regards,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

I was completely in the wrong direction. Live rendering does not insert a header tag but it adds a class with a corresponding style which makes it look like a header.